# ASP.NET MVC URL/Routing question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am an MVC newbie.  I'm trying to get my URLs to look like this:

> /Corporate/Users/Edit/1
>   /Corporate/Stores/Edit/17
>   /Corporate/Contacts/Edit/17
>   /Store/Contacts/Create
>   /Store/Products/Edit/29

Pretty much like plain-vanilla urls, except with a user type at the front.  I'm running into a lot of problems with duplicate controller names, etc.

Is there a simple way to do this?  I looked briefly at Areas, but this seemed way to complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    RouteNames.Default, // Route name
    "{userType}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    );
```

and then

```
public ActionResult LogIn(string userType)
{
    return View();
}
```

or

```
public ActionResult LogIn()
{
    var userType = RouteData.Values["userType"];
    return View();
}
```

where needed or define BaseController:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private string _userType;

    public BaseController()
    {
        _userType = RouteData.Values["userType"];
    }
}
```